# set date without time in D3 js

Tags: json, d3.js

I am working on D3 js.
I am a Lerner and trying to render the multi line graph but i am not able to set proper date format.i wanted to remove 12 PM .example like **April 12 PM Wed 02**

below is my code

```
var margin = { top: 40, right: 40, bottom: 35, left: 85 },
    width = 800 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 350 - margin.top - margin.bottom;




    var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y%m%d").parse;

    var x = d3.time.scale()
    .range([0, width]);

    var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

    var color = d3.scale.category10();

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left");

    var line = d3.svg.line()
    .interpolate("basis")
    .x(function (d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function (d) { return y(d.request); });

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    //d3.tsv("data.tsv", function (error, data) {
    color.domain(d3.keys(data.ListWeekly[0]).filter(function (key) { return key !== "date"; }));

        data.ListWeekly.forEach(function (d) {
            d.date = parseDate(d.date);

        });

        var cities = color.domain().map(function (name) {
            return {
                name: name,
                values: data.ListWeekly.map(function (d) {
                    return { date: d.date, request: +d[name] };
                })
            };
        });

        x.domain(d3.extent(data.ListWeekly, function (d) { return d.date; }));

        y.domain([
    d3.min(cities, function (c) { return d3.min(c.values, function (v) { return v.request; }); }),
    d3.max(cities, function (c) { return d3.max(c.values, function (v) { return v.request; }); })
  ]);

        svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

        svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Request");

        var city = svg.selectAll(".city")
      .data(cities)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "city");

        city.append("path")
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", function (d) { return line(d.values); })
      .style("stroke", function (d) { return color(d.name); });

        city.append("text")
      .datum(function (d) { return { name: d.name, value: d.values[d.values.length - 1] }; })
      .attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + x(d.value.date) + "," + y(d.value.request) + ")"; })
      .attr("x", 3)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .text(function (d) { return d.name; });
    //});
```

**my json data**

```
var List = new List<object>();
List.Add(new { date = "20140401", weekday = "163", weekend = "263" });
                List.Add(new { date = "20140402", weekday = "153", weekend = "253" });
                List.Add(new { date = "20140403", weekday = "133", weekend = "233" });
                List.Add(new { date = "20140404", weekday = "167", weekend = "373" });
                List.Add(new { date = "20140405", weekday = "123", weekend = "183" });
                List.Add(new { date = "20140406", weekday = "178", weekend = "123" });
                List.Add(new { date = "20140407", weekday = "32", weekend = "223" });

  return Json(new { ListWeekly = List });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the time format using the [`d3.time.format`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Formatting#format) helper and set the format of the tick labels of the axis using the axis [`tickFormat`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes#wiki-tickFormat) method. To have the dates formatted as `2014-04-30`, you can use the following code:

```
// Create a time format generator
var dateFmt = d3.time.format('%Y-%m-%d');  // 2014-04-30

// The dateFmt function returns a string with the formatted date
console.log(dateFmt(new Date('2014/04/04')); // 2014-04-04

// Set the tick format for the xAxis
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
   .scale(x)
   .orient("bottom")
   .tickFormat(function(d) { return dateFmt(d.date); });
```

Comment: i have tried but still it's not working..please suggest

Comment: Can you write a jsFiddle? It will be easier to help you if I can run your code.